# curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/nodes?pretty=true' getting ERROR

Tags: elasticsearch

For Elastic search clustering in Linux box 
   1) create 3 folder with Elastic-Node1,Elastic-Node2,Elastic-Node3
   2) started 3 nodes with  ./bin/elasticsearch

```
---Node1
[2014-09-03 11:20:24,731][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Danger] detected_master [Virako][B7jkVnNsQIiLeSwIrkjhQA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x23:9300]], added {[Alexander Summers][BkpTVquYRnyswIVyaZuYuA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x13:9300]],[Conquest][2ZYcVV3USFmmrewPld7z0Q][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x13:9302]],[Virako][B7jkVnNsQIiLeSwIrkjhQA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x23:9300]],[logstash-localhost.localdomain-2467-4038][smpAKj2iSp2bN7xvEYoM7g][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x13:9303]]{client=true, data=false},[logstash-localhost.localdomain-2163-4002][0zV7dRPgRqyTmRcbfw_5nA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x13:9301]]{client=true, data=false},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[Virako][B7jkVnNsQIiLeSwIrkj

---Node2
[2014-09-03 11:21:16,552][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [NFL Superpro] detected_master [Virako][B7jkVnNsQIiLeSwIrkjhQA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x23:9300]], added {[Danger][UqpWF27oQ7-TKkIJ63EOCQ][master][inet[/192.xxx.x88:9300]],[Alexander Summers][BkpTVquYRnyswIVyaZuYuA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x13:9300]],[Conquest][2ZYcVV3USFmmrewPld7z0Q][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x13:9302]],[Virako][B7jkVnNsQIiLeSwIrkjhQA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x23:9300]],[logstash-localhost.localdomain-2467-4038][smpAKj2iSp2bN7xvEYoM7g][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x13:9303]]{client=true, data=false},[logstash-localhost.localdomain-2163-4002][0zV7dRPgRqyTmRcbfw_5nA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x13:9301]]{client=true, data=false},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[Virako][B7jkVnNsQIiLeSwIrkjhQA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x23:9300]]])

----Node3
[2014-09-03 11:21:38,434][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.multicast] [Catiana] received ping response ping_response{target [[NFL Superpro][dyjRr-ctRgmd8tpI2y397A][master][inet[/192.xxx.x88:9301]]], master [[Virako][B7jkVnNsQIiLeSwIrkjhQA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x23:9300]]], cluster_name[elasticsearch]} with no matching id [1]
[2014-09-03 11:21:38,437][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.multicast] [Catiana] received ping response ping_response{target [[Danger][UqpWF27oQ7-TKkIJ63EOCQ][master][inet[/192.xxx.x88:9300]]], master [[Virako][B7jkVnNsQIiLeSwIrkjhQA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x23:9300]]], cluster_name[elasticsearch]} with no matching id [1]
[2014-09-03 11:21:39,155][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Catiana] detected_master [Virako][B7jkVnNsQIiLeSwIrkjhQA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x23:9300]], added {[Danger][UqpWF27oQ7-TKkIJ63EOCQ][master][inet[/192.xxx.x88:9300]],[Alexander Summers][BkpTVquYRnyswIVyaZuYuA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x13:9300]],[Conquest][2ZYcVV3USFmmrewPld7z0Q][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x13:9302]],[Virako][B7jkVnNsQIiLeSwIrkjhQA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x23:9300]],[logstash-localhost.localdomain-2467-4038][smpAKj2iSp2bN7xvEYoM7g][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x13:9303]]{client=true, data=false},[NFL Superpro][dyjRr-ctRgmd8tpI2y397A][master][inet[/192.xxx.x88:9301]],[logstash-localhost.localdomain-2163-4002][0zV7dRPgRqyTmRcbfw_5nA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x13:9301]]{client=true, data=false},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[Virako][B7jkVnNsQIiLeSwIrkjhQA][localhost.localdomain][inet[/192.xxx.x23:9300]]])
```

3)when i am starting Curl with help its giving me

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 7,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 5,
  "active_primary_shards" : 70,
  "active_shards" : 140,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 142
}
```

4)on `curl -XGET 'http://192.xxx.x.xx:9200/_cluster/nodes?pretty=true`" I am getting

```
No handler found for uri [/_cluster/nodes?pretty=true] and method [GET][
```

Comment: Try http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats? I am not sure _cluster/nodes is a thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `/_cluster/nodes` API in the [elasticsearch documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster.html).  You probably want the [/_cluster/state](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-state.html) API.  There's also some good [/_cat](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html) APIs that are easier to read.  In particular if you are trying to figure out what shards aren't allocated, you can use the [/_cat/shards](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-shards.html) API.  You can also use the [/_cat/nodes](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html) to see what nodes are currently in the cluster (and you can pass some extra parameters to see a table view of other things).